# jQuery $.each() returns only the first element from a Json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, each

I want to populate the contents of #city div dynamically from $.each() function that loops through an Json object (result). How can I get all the elements from the object an put them in the #city div?

What is the best way to create and replace html elements in this situation? (from am each function)

My code:

```
<div id="city"></div>
```

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/Home/GetCity",
        type: "GET",
        data: { county: County}
    })
    .done(function (result) {
        $.each(result, function (index, value) {
            console.log(this.CityName); //here it returns all the elements
           $('#city').html("<h4>" + this.CityName+ "</h4>"); //here it return only the first one

       });
    });
```

Comment: I would suggest to use for loop instead of each.

Comment: You'll probably want to post the sample JSON to make sure that looks fine. You'll also want to use `append` instead of `html`, as `html` replaces the content entirely.

Comment: @Armen, any particular reason?

Comment: The problem that you have is .html, now I see, every time you are replacing the whole html, so at the end the last item will be show up.

Comment: @Armen but the question states it returns the first element, not the last.

Comment: What is the order of elements in log? what is the last element?

Comment: @alex87, can you show an example of what `result` might look like?

Comment: the order is as it should be, this is from a query. Every time I click on another element the #city div should replace the content not append to it

Comment: can you show an example of `result` so we can see the structure, did you try the answer below btw?

Comment: [Object, Object, Object, Object]
 0: Object
  City: "Barcelona"
  URLUniv: "http://www.citybarcelona.com/"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are overwritting all the values because you are using "html" jquery function.
I recommend to use append:

```
$('#city').empty().append("<h4>" + this.CityName+ "</h4>");
```

Comment: this returns all the elements but it adds them, I want to replace the content of the div every time I click on another html element

Comment: What do you mean? Could you give me an example to understand your point?

Comment: this hole process is in an click event of a html map area. Every map area has an id. Every time i click a map area an ajax request goes to an action method with the id parameter, that returns a sql query in form of a Json object. So every time I click a (different) map area it should show me the cities from that area(county).

Comment: So, the "html" function is correct if you want to rewrite the #city div. Do you have your $.ajax call inside a click event? Because you can bind any click in your map and call the ajax.

Comment: Could you update the question with the html map, the jquery event and more information?

Comment: I found that it works if i put `$('#city').empty()` line first in the click event, and then in the ajax call in the each function I use `$('#city').append("<h4>" + this.CityName+ "</h4>")` **But is this ok** ?

Comment: Yes, the append function won't clean your html code. The "html" function do it. So if you empty the #city div, and it works...great :)